# ubuntu hotspot wifi for captive portal and authentication via sms

Tags: 14.04, hot-spot

I'm trying to install GRASE HotSpot on Ubuntu 14.04lts to realize an hotspot wifi for the captive portal and using sms for authentication users.

But during the installation I've received that error:

**`$: sudo apt-get install grase-www-portal grase-conf-freeradius grase-conf-squid3 grase-conf-openvpn`**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grase-conf-squid3 : Depends: squid3 (< 3.2) but 3.3.8-1ubuntu6.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

it requests a lower release of squid and in fact on its own guide GRASE has been installed on a 12.04.

Any suggests to create a hotspot wifi for the captive portal and authentication via SMS using ubuntu 14.04lts?

Thanks in advance

B.R. 
Riccardo

Comment: someone can suggest me something about that?

Answer (score 1):

To view the available versions of a package you can do:

```
apt-cache show <package_name>
```

In your case squid3 doesn't exist in a version < 3.2 in trusty.

You can, however, find an older .deb at http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/squid3/ in particular the 3.1.19 version should satisfy your requirements, provided that it doesn't have dependencies itself which cannot be met by the trusty repos.